# unsigned(0) - 1 generates "segment fault"

Tags: types, type-conversion

why below code generates "segment fault" when foo.size() is 0. Is it because type conversion ?

```
 int main()
 {
   vector <int> foo;
   for (int i = 0; i < foo.size() - 1; i++) {
       cout << foo[i] << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because size is unsigned. If you subtract 0 from an unsigned number, you get the max value for that number. Try:

```
if(foo.size() > 0)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < foo.size() - 1; i++)
  {
    cout << foo[i] << endl;
  }
}
```

Or, simpler solution, just avoid subtracting. Add instead.

```
for(int i = 0; i + 1 < foo.size(); i++)
{
  cout << foo[i] << endl;
}
```

You can tell exactly what's happening in your code if you print out `foo.size() - 1` when foo has 0 elements. On my end, it prints 18446744073709551615. That is a very big, non-negative number.

**More on unsigned numbers**

When you subtract 1 from an unsigned(0), the bits of your number all change to 1's (they go from all 0's to all 1's). This is because typically, negative numbers are expressed in a form known as Two's Complement - to make a number negative, you flip all of the bits of the number, and add 1 to the result.

For negative one (example will be in 4 bits):

```
0001 = 4
1110 = flipped
1111 = flipped + 1
```

So, in four bit two's complement, -1 is expressed as all ones.

Therefore, subtracting 1 from 0000 should give you 1111.

But how does a computer know if a number is negative?
Simple. It assumes that any number with the leftmost bit set is a negative number.

This is all well and good, but that means that there's one less bit you can use for storing LARGE numbers.

If you use the most significant bit to denote the sign of a number for an 8 bit number, the largest number you can express drops from 255 to 127.

For this reason, we occasionally treat numbers as unsigned so that we can store large values. The downside is that if we subtract anything from 0, we will get a result that usually denotes a negative number, but interpret it as a really large positive number.

Similarly, if you have a 32 bit integer set to the largest possible number that can be expressed in 32 bits (assume unsigned), and add 1 to it, the number will wrap around, back to 0.

These issues are referred to as overflow and underflow.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I already tried on my computer . However I am not clear about what is going on behind the scene when  (unsinged int) 0 - 1.  Could you clarify here ? Many thanks

Comment: I modified my answer a bit to explain this a bit more under the text "More on unsigned numbers".